# Android Studio Could not find any matches for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+ as no versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 are available

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a new android application project in android studio. Running the project in Android Studio fails with this error:

```
*A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
  Could not find any matches for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+ as no 
  versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 are available.*
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you download all the relevant SDKs from the SDKManager in your case API level 19+?

Comment: In my sdk manager only show the installed pakages. and when click on the message for download sdk repository show this message :There is nothing to install or update.

Comment: Android Studio recently changed their view you may have to click the "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" to get a better view, then make sure at least 1 APi 19+ is fully installed / updated.

Comment: "Launch Standalone SDK Manager"  is not exist.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your SDK Manager section

Comment: please see this link:----->  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B13lB0g6pfmcS1p6elJBRG8waG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You seem to have a lot of data missing, its seems you may not have installed Android Studio properly, check for updates also check you SDK Path, try looking in AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Answer (score 1):

From Android Studio go to: Tools > Android > SDK Manager

Select and install "Extras > Android Support Repository"

Comment: In  my sdk manager no exist this option :Extras > Android Support Repository

Answer (score 0):

Step1) Go to project structure setting in Android Studio

step2) On left side select you project and then goto dependencies (can be found on the top portion)

step3) Remove current appcompact-v7  and click Add button and select appcompact-v7.23.0.0 and clean your project .it will solve

Comment: I do this but when add the appcompat-v7 show message that library compat-v7 is not installed.Install repository? then I click ok .and show this message: There is nothing to install or update.

Comment: go to Android Sdk Manager and see in Extra section that you have already install Android support library and version 17 or more than that